# Java: Problems creating a tree structure using java Generics

Tags: java, generics, gwt, tree

I have an application that requires data to be displayed on a report screen on a website using GWT. This information needs to be grouped in a tree like structure with each layer of the tree being a different type of grouping.

For example data might need to be grouped by date, then by region and then by vehicle. However on another similar report the data may need to be grouped in a different order, say vehicle, date, region.

As such I created a tree structure using generics, with each type of grouping being a subclass of a tree node. A simplistic version of the code is below.

```
public abstract class Node extends Composite implements Comparable<Node>
{
    //sorts the subtree of this node using the comparable interface
    //and by calling each of the child nodes sort methods
    public abstract sort();

    //when called will draw this node and its entire subtree to the UI
    //again by calling the child nodes draw method.
    protected abstract draw();
}

public abstract class ParentNode<E extends Node> extends Node
{
    private List<E> children = new ArrayList<E>();

    public void addChild( E child )
    {
        children.add( child );
    }

    public List<E> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort( children )

        for( E child : children )
        child.sort();
    }
}

public class DateGrouping<E> extends ParentNode<Node>
{
    public void draw()
    { ... }
}

public class Data extends Node
{...}

public class Report
{
    private RootNode<DateGrouping<RegionGrouping<VehicleGrouping<Data>>>> rootNode;

    public Report()
    {
        rootNode = new RootNode<DateGrouping<RegionGrouping<VehicleGrouping<Data>>>>();
    }
}
```

Note: Other group types are defined in the same manner as DateGrouping

The main problem I have with this implementation is that calling

```
rootNode.getChildren()
```

in the above example returns

```
List<Node> object
```

not

```
List<DateGrouping<RegionGrouping<VehicleGrouping<Data>>>>
```

This means I have to do a bunch of dirty casting to be able to use the objects that are returned.

Is there a way to avoid doing the casting, or a better way of coding my tree so I don't have to worry about it?

Comment: Strange, in my case (jdk1.7.0_01) `rootNode.getChildren()` correctly returns `List <DateGrouping <RegionGrouping <VehicleGrouping <Data>>>>`. What Java version do you use?

Comment: The project I am working on is still using 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you haven't shown us `RootNode` class implementation.
But if you implemented it the same way as  `DateGrouping` then behavior is correct. Look closely how you implement interface at `DateGrouping`

> public class DateGrouping<*E*> extends ParentNode<*Node*>

You don't pass type parameter E to the `ParentNode` . So `getChildren()` will return `List<Node>`, not `List<E>`

Comment: This looks like the problem. Should be

public class DateGrouping<E extends Node> extends ParentNode<E>

I will test this when I'm back at work on Monday. Thanks.